# how to clear heap memory in android after copying a 5mb datafile to database?

Tags: android

I am trying to copy a 5mb database file to data folder from raw folder of my application.

I can copy it some times successfully.But after that i cannot click on images, while clicking i am getting `OutOfMemory`-exception.

so am trying to clear heap memory. is there any way to do that.

```
private void copyFromZipFile() throws IOException{
     InputStream is = mycontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dbfile);
         // Path to the just created empty db
         File outFile = new File(DB_PATH ,DB_NAME);
          //Open the empty db as the output stream
         OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
         ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
          try {
              ZipEntry ze;
              while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                  int count;
                  while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                      try
                      {
                      baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                     Log.d("", "writing..."+buffer.toString());
                      }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                          Log.v("","Error writing"+e );
                    }
                  }
                  baos.writeTo(myOutput);


              }
          } finally {
              zis.close();
              myOutput.flush();
              myOutput.close();
              is.close();
          }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code which copies the file.

Comment: the garbage collector should do this for you please show us your code

Comment: @sherif  Knuth -Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first `while`-loop, you are recreating the `ByteArrayOutputStream` for every iteration. You are not closing it and you don't explicitly set it to `null` after you're done, so this is a Memory-Leak because the garbage-collector can't collect the instance.

A better approach would be moving the creation of `baos`, `buffer` and `count` out of the loop and using the [`reset()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) on the `ByteArrayOutputStream` after you wrote to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to compress a binary file? SQLite files can be compressed, sometimes quite efficiently too (depending on what's in the database).

Comment: Binary-files should be compressed already. I'm not sure if you benefit that much from compressing a SQLite Database.

Comment: What makes you think that? Indeed, some binary formats (like JPEG) are made of compressed data (although the compression level can in fact be set when saving the file), but not all of them. (I've just tried on a SQLite file I have, I can gzip it and reduce its size by about 70%.)

Comment: I tried it myself, you're right. Miss-understanding on my side, I took it out of the post. Thanks for setting me correct here.